# Dynamic CSS in typescript - How to access parameter passed to the `useStyles` method

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jss, css-in-js

I'm trying to access the state of my component in the `useStyles` method created using the react-jss package.
The code seems to be correct for javascript but not for typescript according to what I found online.

```
import { createUseStyles } from 'react-jss';

const useStyles = createUseStyles({
  myClass: {
    height: `${height}px`, // <== squiggly line here since I don't know how to pass the parameters
  },
});

export function Collapse() {

  const [height, setHeight] = useState(18);
  const classes = useStyles(height);

  return (
    <div>...</div>
  );
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: const useStyles = createUseStyles({
  myClass: props => ({
    height: `${props.height}px`
  })
});

Comment: Thank you, I updated my code. I can't use props here. Also `props` is unknown too.

Comment: I have updated my code. Please check. Please refer to the link https://github.com/cssinjs/jss/issues/1273

Comment: Thank you very much, I managed to achieve what I wanted.

Comment: @Ploppy Consider posting an answer to your question if you found the solution yourself/ with help from the comments. This will help anyone who comes across this question since the link from K.Raj may become unavailable after time.

Comment: Done, I have another one that I'm running into, you may have the solution! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65288934/how-to-access-the-ref-of-child-element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a function in my styles allows me to access the desired parameter.

```
import { createUseStyles } from 'react-jss';

const useStyles = createUseStyles({
  myClass: props => ({
    height: `${height}px`,
  }),
});

export function Collapse() {

  const [height, setHeight] = useState(18);
  const classes = useStyles({height: height});

  return (
    <div>...</div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it is better to make types clear when you are using `jss` and `typescript` together. in this case you need to specify type of parameters you want to pass them to `jss`. (read [this article](https://medium.com/weekly-webtips/the-best-and-most-different-way-to-create-styles-in-react-apps-using-jss-and-typescript-e7aad6d28b86) for better understanding)

in [v10.6.0](https://github.com/cssinjs/jss/releases/tag/v10.6.0) of `jss` they added a feature to specify types of parameters you pass them to `jss` in a more handy way.
in your case, first of all we specify classNames and types precisely:

```
import { Classes, Styles } from "jss";
import { createUseStyles } from "react-jss";

type CollapseStyleProps = { height?: number };
type CollapseClassNames = "myClass";
type CollapseClasses = Classes<CollapseClassNames>;
type CollapseStyles = Styles<CollapseClassNames, CollapseStyleProps>; //we specify types of props here
```

and then we will write styles in `jss`:

```
const getStyles: CollapseStyles = {
  myClass: {
    height: ({ height }) => height,
    transition: "500ms"
  }
};

const useCollapseStyle: (data?: any) => CollapseClasses = createUseStyles(getStyles);
```

now in the last step, start implementing `Collapse` component itself:

```
function Collapse() {
  const [height, setHeight] = useState(18);
  const classes = useCollapseStyle({ height });

  const heightHandler = () => {
    height === 18 ? setHeight(108) : setHeight(18);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className={classes.myClass}>Test App</div>
      <button onClick={heightHandler}>toggle height</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

you can see working example here on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-wave-r2nyn?file=/src/App.tsx)