# How to access the ref of child element

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a reveal/collapse animation, I need to access the height of the animated element. So I need its reference inside the component that does the animation (named `CollapseTransition`). I can pass the `ref` by creating one in the parent component and forwarding it to the animation component but it's in my opinion way to much code, I would like to NOT write javascript when using my animation component.

Is there a way to access the `ref` of `children` exclusiveley in the `CollapseTransition` component that I created?

```
const refTransitionnedElement = useRef(null);

return (
  <div>
    <CollapseTransition visible={visible} ref={refTransitionnedElement}>
      <div ref={refTransitionnedElement}>test</div>
    </CollapseTransition>
  </div>
);
```

```
export const CollapseTransition = forwardRef((props: { visible: boolean; children: any; }, ref) => {

  //[...]

  return (
    <>[...]</>
  );
});
```

Ultimatedly, I would like use my `CollapseTransition` component like this:

```
<CollapseTransition visible={visible}>
  <div>test</div>
</CollapseTransition>
```

While being able to access the height of the div in my `CollapseTransition` component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use render props pattern here.

```
export const CollapseTransition = (props: { visible: boolean; children: any; }) => {

  const refTransitionnedElement = useRef(null);

  return (
    <>{children(refTransitionnedElement)}</>
  );
});
```

And you use it this way.

```
return (
  <div>
    <CollapseTransition visible={visible}>
    {(refTransitionnedElement) => (
      <div ref={refTransitionnedElement}>test</div>
    )}
    </CollapseTransition>
  </div>
);
```

Or you can use React.children.map (it's compound components pattern).

```
export const CollapseTransition = (props: { visible: boolean; children: any; }) => {
    
      const refTransitionnedElement = useRef(null);
    
      return (
        <>{React.Children.map(children, (child) => {
          return React.cloneElement(child, {
              ref: refTransitionnedElement
          });
        })}</>
      );
    });
```

And use it this way

```
<CollapseTransition visible={visible}>
  <div>test</div>
</CollapseTransition>
```

With this compound components solution you need to asure that there is only one child of the CollapseTransition element.

Comment: Your first solution works, the second one looks even better but I can't manage to get it to work. It seems like you did not implement the map function correctly.

Comment: Try now. I fixed the calling of react.children.map. First argument should be children array :)

Comment: Thank you, I managed to test it in a isolated component and it works. Unfortunately as I'm applying transitions using the `react-transition-group` package I can't seem to clone the components as it throws all sort of errors.